# Bootstrap dropdown list-group/collapsable menu remain open when user click on link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap dropdowns, how can I make a menu stay open when a user clicks on a link?

Here is a [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3h6wbzmh/) of what I have tried.

I have tried the following code but using this the links no longer work.

```
 $('#SubMenu1 > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if(!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
        var lastActive = $(this).closest("#SubMenu1").children(".active");
        lastActive.removeClass("active");
        lastActive.next('div').collapse('hide');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        $(this).next('div').collapse('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: "stay open when a user clicks on a link" - what link?

Comment: call another page and display on the right side of the page.